# Jruby, Garbage Collector, Redis

Tags: memory, jruby, redis, store

I have an Jruby On Rails app which uses several WS's to gather data. The app processes the data displays it to the user, the user make his changes and then is sent back to the WS.

The problem here is that i store everything in the cache (session based) which is using memory store. But from time to time with no clear reason (for me at least) this error pops up:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (GC overhead limit exceeded)
```

I read what I could find about it and apparently this means that the Garbage Collector spends to much time in trying to free memory and no real progress is being made in that direction. My guess is that since everything is stored cache like into memory the GC tries to free it and can't do it and throws this error.

So here are the questions.

- How can I get around this ?
- If I switch from memory store to Redis, if my assumptions are correct, will this problem still appear.
- Will the GC try to free Redis's memory area ? (Might be a stupid question but ... please help nonetheless :) )

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Redis is a separate process, so your app garbage collector won't touch it. However, it is possible that redis is using up all the memory that would otherwise be available for the app, or that you are actually using a process memory cache and not redis, which is a different type of memory store.